# How do I detect when a user edits a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that deletes a message if a substring is found within it. Someone bypassed it by editing their message. How do I detect when a user edits a message in discord.py rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure to [update discord.py to v1.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/#installing) and [enable guild messages intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#what-intents-are-needed) if you haven't already. (For safety, I recommend [enabling all intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.all) in both your code and the [Discord Developer Portal.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#what-intents-are-needed))

Now, we make use of the [`on_message_edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit) event, like so:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if before.content != after.content:
        if 'substring' in after.content:
            # do something here
```